# Jade conditional (if/else) to add class to div inline

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Is there a way to do this inline in a jade template?

```
if(typeof fromEdit != 'undefined')
   div#demo.collapse.in
else
   div#demo.collapse
```

Would like to do this conditional check "inline" and the result would add the .in to the end of the div if fromEdit exists.

Comment: i use this `a(class=(selectNav=='myprofile' && 'selected'), href='...')`

Answer (score 116, accepted):

This works:

```
div#demo.collapse(class=typeof fromEdit === "undefined" ? "" : "in")
```

Try it out [here](http://naltatis.github.com/jade-syntax-docs/).

Comment: but you wouldn't even want the element to have a `class` attribute if the condition is false..

Comment: How to do it for object value like 
a(class=tasks[i].status ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-dark', href=`/turn/ ${tasks[i]._id}`) Done

showing error
Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Answer (score 83):

If you don't want the class attribute to be added when there is no value, you can assign it undefined instead of an empty string. Here is the previous example, slightly modified:

```
div#demo.collapse(class=typeof fromEdit === "undefined" ? undefined : "in")
```

Update: Also, if you are using [pug](https://pugjs.org/), you can now add as many `class=` declarations as you want with different conditions and they'll get concatenated in the resulting class attribute. e.g.:

```
#demo.collapse(class=cond1 && 'class1' class=cond2 && 'class2')
```

Comment: What about a case when there are multiple condition must be checked? For example two classes each with its own check?

Answer (score 6):

As documented at http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/:

> The class attribute [...] It can also be an object mapping class names to true or false values, which is useful for applying conditional classes

the task can be also done by the following:

```
div#demo.collapse(class={ in: typeof fromEdit != 'undefined' })
```

Although it doesn't work here http://naltatis.github.com/jade-syntax-docs/ (I think they need to update something), but it works with jade@1.11.0 .

Comment: This is the way to go now with jade/pug. It allows multiple conditionnal classes, with adding another key to the object.

Answer (score 3):

With pug 2 you can use this syntax:

```
div#demo(class="collapse", class={"in": typeof fromEdit !== 'undefined'}) Home page
```

more here: https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html

Answer (score 2):

Though an old question, I find that the following works since Pug includes object existence detection built in:

```
div#demo.collapse(class=fromEdit? 'in':undefined)
```

If it's not obvious, this checks if `fromEdit` exists and if it does enters `in` as the class, otherwise leaving the class blank.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple conditional classes

```
p(class={"true-class": isTrue, "false-class": !isTrue})
```