# is there jade plugin that would allow manipulation using jquery styled syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, templating

So say if i have li elements, and i want to use java script to a) find element with class X then add modify some attribute of it.

I can run usual JavaScript and it'd be doable, but i have no idea of how to get handle of existing elements and manipulate them. Can you refer to element with in jade, preferably like in jquery `$('.a').has(..)` This is new idea i haven't seen it mentioned anywhere before.

Usually it's server side ( you manually modify elements ) or you send data along template to client where javascript can tackled actual elements.

Comment: You would have to make JQuery available to your jade templates in order to use it. Otherwise, you have to use vanilla JavaScript

Comment: how can i do it using vanilla then?

Comment: You can also use interpolation. http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/

Comment: @sctskw can you explain what i can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does more or less what i wanted. And it's natively supported. It's called conditional attributes in docs.

You can find more information about it in attribute section.

Only works with latest version of jade.

```
//- Suppose object passed is this
- var selected='about';
li(class={selected:selected=="home"}) Home
li(class={selected:selected=="blog"}) Blog
li(class={selected:selected=="about"}) About
```

..Will result in this:

```
<li>Home</li>
<li>Blog</li>
<li class="selected">About</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need and shouldn't manipulate your markup before you rending it.
Just create a jade mixin where you can pass params to customize your markup output.

If you want a more precise answer, provide a concrete example how you would do it in jQuery.

If you want to change a DOM on the server side, you can use [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio), but for rendering templates for the client you should never do this!

Comment: example, i have nav header with li type menu items. i want to apply selected to li which is in `.nav` and has id `#about`. So i can pass object like this to parser `{selected:'about', title:'about'...}`

Comment: Then you should just do an inline css conditional using a template var.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144274/jade-conditional-if-else-to-add-class-to-div-inline