# How to add class in jade using if statement of jinja

Tags: if-statement, pug, jinja2

I am using `jade` instead of `HTML` and `jinja` template. I need to add a particular class after checking some variables value.

`section.all-articles.large-7.columns`

Here in the above line of code I need to add another class `.mid`

```
{% if articles|length < 10 %}
//add a class .mid
{% endif %}
```

And I want my resultant as

`section.all-articles.large-7.columns.mid` when its converted to html.

Comment: Check out these posts.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144274/jade-conditional-if-else-to-add-class-to-div-inline
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668881/variable-in-class-name-jade

Answer (score 0):

```
section.all-articles.large-7.columns#ko-container(class!="{% if articles|length < 10 %}mid{% endif %}")
```