# How to control markup indents with Javascript present?

Tags: node.js, pug

I want to output an iterative list of:

```
<div class='X'>  //or plain <div> depending on boolean X
  <div class='d1'>
    <div class='d2'>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Jade script is:

```
each r in rList
   -if (X)
       div.X
          div.d1
             div.d2
   -else
       div
          div.d1
             div.d2
```

How do I do it with just one set of `d1` and `d2` which are the same in both situations?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144274/jade-conditional-if-else-to-add-class-to-div-inline

Comment: Hi, thanks. I could solve this particular (simple) problem of mine by converting to an inline conditional expression. I wonder if there is a more generic way to  specify indents to achieve the hierarchy I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
each r in rList
  div(class=X ? X : '')
    div.d1
      div.d2
```

or you can drop the 'div's:

```
each r in rList
  div(class=X ? X : '')
    .d1
      .d2
```